# Recover from a JSONException

Tags: java, android, json

I am parsing a `JSON` result, but sometimes it is malformed e.g. if the website was down. When I try parse that on my app I get a `JSONException` (because it is valid `JSON`). I am wanting to then print a message to the user saying try again later and not have the app crash, but I haven't had much luck.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html) it says

> Although this is a checked exception, it is rarely recoverable. Most
>   callers should simply wrap this exception in an unchecked exception
>   and rethrow:

If I am reading that correctly then I won't be able to print the message to the user and keep the app 
from crashing. If that is correct, what are the few times it can be done (under what conditions)?

Comment: Catch the exception and do the rest gracefully

Comment: You can catch it with no problem

Comment: "if the website was down" ... you should have noticed that *way* before you got to using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote just means that you have to check for the exception either by using a try/catch or adding "throws JSONException" to your method signature, and even though you have to check for it, you normally can't really fix it, so just throw a RuntimeException or something.

You can definitely handle it gracefully, though. Here's something to get your started:

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    // crazy stuff that might throw a JSONException
} catch (JSONException e) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title_error)
        .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message_error)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    alert.show();

}
```